# Swift: Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on update function

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to make a simple application with rain effect. To create this I am using a simple spark image and make it fall from a cloud. However, when I am attempting to use the random function to randomly generate a random number for the x-coordinate position for the spark to appear, xCode throws an unexpected error:

**Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)**

Here is the code used to create this simple application:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Particles: SKScene{

    let cloud = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cloud")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        cloud.size = CGSize(width: 210, height: 100)
        cloud.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.size.width/2, y:self.frame.size.height*0.9)
        cloud.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5)
        self.addChild(cloud)

//        var rain = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "rainParticle.sks")
//        rain!.position = CGPoint(x:cloud.position.x, y:cloud.position.y-cloud.size.height/2)
//        self.addChild(rain!)
    }

    func particle_spawn(pos_x:Int){
        let particle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spark")
        particle.name = "spark"
        particle.size = CGSize(width: 10, height:10)
        particle.position = CGPoint(x: cloud.position.x+CGFloat(pos_x), y: cloud.position.y-cloud.size.width/2)
        self.addChild(particle)
        let fall = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x:0,y:0), duration: 1)
        particle.runAction(fall)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        let distance_change = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(40))-20)
        particle_spawn(distance_change)
    }

}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error? If yes, can you explain me what this error means and why I get it with as much explanation as possible please?

**NOTE:** English is not my first language.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get a crash because you are basically creating 60 spark SKSpriteNodes every 1 second. (update is called 60 times per frame).

Imagine you would play for 10 seconds, you would have created 600 SKSpriteNodes.

Usually you create the rain particles like you have done (and commented out)

```
 let rain = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "rainParticle.sks")
 ...
```

than in the rainParticle.sks file you can set up things such as spawn rate, how many particles spawn, how fast they move etc.

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/particle-emitter-tutorial-sprite-kit-swift

If you use the sprite kit particles files there is a template just for rain, which you can than change/tweak to your liking.

Hope this helps.